# Technic pin on a pole: is it an illegal technique?

Tags: technic, building

I have two 2714b pieces that I want to put together to make a longer pole. Is sliding the technic pin of one pole over the end of another pole illegal? (If it is, how else could I make a long and thin pole like this?)

[image]

Comment: I dunno if puting a pin in that hole is legal, but my guess would be LEGO would not do this because such a construction would be relatively fragile and easy to snap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLG has been using "bar inside Technic pin" technique, so I assume this is considered legal connection. One thing to consider though - some newer elements with pins are no longer round inside, so you cannot fit *bar* type of element there anymore.

One example from 42043 set (I'm sure there are more examples, but this is something I had in my head immediately):

Roof assembly has these LBG [Technic, Pin 1/2 with 2L Bar Extension (Flick Missile)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61184&idColor=86#T=C&C=86)

[image]

Later, in Step 64, you have horns attached with half pins.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that bar type elements don't fit any more in pins? Do you have an online resource to support that claim? I've built recent technic sets and the pins didn't seem altered that drastically...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve Correction: not a pin, but a connector with pins - newer version of [Technic Pin Double with Axle Hole](https://rebrickable.com/parts/65098/technic-pin-double-with-axle-hole-squared-holes/) has been changed and doesn't accept bar elements.

Comment: interesting, seems worth an SE question and answer on its own...